OpenLayers: can I get a color which gets by overlaying layers with some opacity?
I have 2 layers with some opacity:
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: function (feature) {
        return new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: *some function to get color from data*
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgb(23, 23, 23)',
                width: 0.5
            }),
        });
    }
});

vectorLayer.setOpacity(0.7)

and 1 "final" layer without opacity:
var finalLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: vectorSource,
    style: function (feature) {
        return new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rbg(255, 255, 255)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgb(23, 23, 23)',
                width: 0.5
            }),
        });
    }
});

So the color I get as a result is the result of overlaying 3 layers
I tried to get the color using
R = R1 + (R2 - R1) * Alfa / 255; 
G = G1 + (G2 - G1) * Alfa / 255; 
B = B1 + (B2 - B1) * Alfa / 255;

but the color I get was not the same I see on the map
The colors of two layers with opacity I store as a feature property:
var color1 = feature.get('color1').match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(Number)
var color2 = feature.get('color2').match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(Number)
const selectStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: function (feature) {
            var color1 = feature.get('color1').match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(Number)
            var color2 = feature.get('color2').match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g).map(Number)
            return rbg(???);
        },
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(30, 210, 255)',
        width: 1,
    }),
});


I think you are not getting expected results because OpenLayers renders layers using source-over by default.  There was an example of using other modes https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/blend-modes.html which has been removed as it could not work in version 6.  In the latest version 9 it will work again https://jsfiddle.net/k3fy042a/ by replacing precompose and postcompose events with prerender and postrender.  screen may be what you are expecting?

@Mike screen seems to be what I am expecting, but looking at it in comparison, I’m quite satisfied with the current blending mode, I was thinking on whether I can get the current color right away or there’s much more behind it? Is it possible to get the color by pixel using rendered canvas?

Actually, I need it to highlight feature on hover, I just don’t know how to get the blended color. Maybe there’s a more appropriate decision…

Any blending with canvas 2d contexts is slightly non-standard as it applies alpha premultiplication.
If you draw rgba(r1, g1, b1, a1) to a blank canvas
then with source-over draw rgba(r2, g2, b2, a2)
so the result is rgba(r3, g3, b3, a3)
the final alpha a3 will be
a3 = a1 * (1 - a2) + a2

while the r3, g3 and b3 values can each be predicted using
c3 = (c1 * a1 * (1 - a2) + c2 * a2) / a3

Working backwards from that if you already have R1, G1 and B1 for your color1 and wish to produce R2, G2 and B2 for your color2 the R, G and B values you would need to use with an opacity of alpha would be
R = R1 + (R2 - R1) / alpha
G = G1 + (G2 - G1) / alpha
B = B1 + (B2 - B1) / alpha

Depending on the values used that could calculate required values outside the 0 to 255 range which would need to be clamp to the value range.  For example you can never make a white background fully black by overlaying it with semi-transparent black or vice versa.
In OpenLayers it might be better to use a Select interaction which replaced the color1 fill with a color2 fill when hovering instead of overlaying and attempting to blend another layer.
